# How to call a webservice programmatically in asp.net

Tags: web-services, asp.net-3.5

How to call webservice programmatically in asp.net without using add web reference?
My webservice url keeps on changing. Hence i need to capture the url at runtime and display the results.
Please advice.

Comment: Specify all of the bindings and transport settings in the web.config. Then create a client-proxy class which implements your web service interface and creates/opens a channel to the endpoint where the service resides.

Answer (score 18):

You can change the URL of a web-reference at runtime (provided that the new address is hosting a service with the same schema that you originally used to create the reference):

```
MyWebService ms = new MyWebService();
ms.Url = "http://example.com/webservice.asmx";
ms.MyWebMethod();
```

Web References are definitely the way to go - whilst the classes that are created by the web reference are usually pretty heavy, all that strong typing makes it well worth your while.

Comment: This seems to be the simplest solution by far. Why is it not getting more love?

Comment: Because Question is to invoke a service dynamically and not by adding web reference and downloading the proxy.

Answer (score 4):

you need to do the following steps.

**PreReq :**
First of all, you know the URL of web service.

**Solution:**
use [wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28VS.71%29.aspx) to create a proxy class and than compile it.

```
wsdl /out:myProxyClass.cs http://hostServer/WebserviceRoot/WebServiceName.asmx?WSDL
```

> (there are other switches available
>   for wsdl. For Example to generate VB
>   class, you need to add switch
>   /language:VB)

Once your proxy class is generated you can easily consume in code.

```
MyProxyClass objService = new MyProxyClass();
DateTime time = objService.GetServerTime(); //Suppose service has  method getServerTime
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks to all for the solutions. What i did is ,i added one webservice as reference. And set its property to dynamic.And then edited the Reference.cs (of the webservice )class's constructor , so as to pass the url dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the end-point URL as part of the constructor of your client-side proxy class.

If you don't need to specify it during runtime then it can also be set in your `web.config` file.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to call the service and where the service file is located?

If the service is located on the same site. Why not just instantiate the class name from the service. Or just create a separate class and use interface